# python reportlab table display Chinese

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

my question is how to display Chinese correctly in reportlab table.

I write a definition:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table


def df_2_pdf(df, fp_pdf):
# Create a PDF document
pdf_filename = fp_pdf
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_filename)

# Load the "simhei" font
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('msyh', r'C:\Windows\Fonts\msyh.ttc'))

# Convert the DataFrame to a list of lists (table data)
table_data = [df.columns] + df.values.tolist()

# Create a Table object and set its properties
table = Table(table_data)
table.setStyle([
    ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 0, 1)),  # Header row text color
    ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),  # Center alignment
    ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'msyh'),  # Use the "simhei" font for the header
    ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 12),  # Header padding
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), (0.9, 0.9, 0.9))  # Header background color
])

# Build the PDF document
doc.build([table])

print(f"PDF file '{pdf_filename}' has been created with the DataFrame.")
```

so, it shows English correctly. But, it cannot show Chinese.
This is a pic.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some research, I find the problem.

> The coordinates are given as (column, row)

```
('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'msyh'),  # Use the "Microsoft YaHei" font for the header
```

Basically, two tuple is to set font 'msyh' for the area I put Chinese character.

(0, 0), (-1, -1) is to set all cell in this font.

This is the result:
[image]